# Applicationhost.config not updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have IIS 7.5 has 80 sites, i located C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config, I opened but found only 4 sites,
Home come? I have no other applicationhost.config on C, when i use MWA.dll I got 80 sites but i'm creating console application that require reading the applicationhost.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You may have [sharedconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/shared-configuration_264) enabled ,check in your IIS manager if
>   you have it enabled

[image: sharedconfig]

Comment: I'm downloading the applicationhost.config from it's default location then parse it with linq to xml in .net, now do u have any idea how can detect this sharedconfig physical path?

Comment: i found it redirection.config :)